# Calculate the width of an image in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have an `image` thats `height` is `100%` of the browser and `width` is `auto`. So the width can vary depending on the picture and the resolution of your screen.

So, I want to calculate the width in the browser thats not taken up by the image.

```
.main-image img {
    width:auto
}
```

> var winheight = $(window).height();
>
> $('.main-image img').css('height', winheight);

So, I was thinking about doing something like this but it wont work.

```
   var findimage = $('.main-image img');
   var imagewidth = findimage.clientHeight;
   console.log("image width is " + imagewidth);
```

However, this `returns` "`image width is undefined`". What should I do?

Comment: check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that an image is not part of the markup, so it has to load before you can retrieve it's width.

```
$('.main-image img').onload(function () {
    console.log("image width is " + $(this).width());
});
```

Comment: I would say that you can probably just do `this.width` onload. No reason to create a jQuery object unless you have another use for that. But this is definitely correct.

Comment: @kalley You are correct, `this.width` would work and it would be more efficient because it doesn't have to be interpreted by the jQuery plugin.

Comment: Uncaught Type error: object [object Object] has no method 'onload'

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$('.main-image img').width()
$('.main-image img').height()
```

and use `Offset` for positioning Left/Top